# python difflib compare output format

Tags: python, compare, difflib

Using difflib.compare with python to compare two text files. I know that the compare returns essentially a list of strings. When a string is unique to the first text file it places a "- " before the string and when the string is unique to the second text file it places a "+ " before the string.

My problem is I'm trying to write some code for determining which string to keep. I started currently looking for the "- " in each string, if i found it I then performed some logic to determine if I was going to use the string or not. If i wasn't going to use it I then either looked one or two lines down for the "+ ".

In almost all of my cases the "- " line preceded the "+ " line. But now I am getting instances where the "+ " line is preceding the "- " line. This is throwing off my code as it can't find the correct line to write to the output text file. Does anyone know the logic behind how the strings are written into the array is it based on whichever line number comes first?

```
ex//
majority of the time out put is this:
"-    color: #ffffff;"
"+    color: #785642;"

but rarely it does come out the opposite:
"+    color: #785642;"
"-    color: #ffffff;"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DIFFERENCE_OUTPUT = []

def find_differences(list1, list2):
    list1 = sorted(list1)
    list2 = sorted(list2)
    for diff in difflib.ndiff(list1,list2): 
        DIFFERENCE_OUTPUT.append(diff)
    for line in DIFFERENCE_OUTPUT:
        if line.startswith("-"):
            #I would suggest change the '-' to the name of the file and print line to see what is there
            line = line.replace('-','NAME of List')
            print(line)
            ****preform task
        elif line.startswith("+"):
            ****preform task
```

All '-' should be for list1 and all '+' should be for list2. If you are seeing a '+' before a '-' that means that list2 has the output but list1 doesn't or vice versa.

Comment: I appreciate the offered help but this doesn't really solve my problem. Why are you using ndiff, as opposed to compare. Correct me if I'm wrong but ndiff is for comparing two lists not text files. Also you run into the same problem as me with the order in which they appear. I need to first search for the "- " lines if it doesn't fit the criteria I have in place then I need to take the other text files version of that line of code. I completely understand what the "+ " and "- " stand for as I stated in my question. I am getting inconsistent formatting of the output.

Comment: Sometimes the first files line of code appears before the second line but then other times its vice versa